# Java HashMap causing ClassCastException

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, iterator, classcastexception

I am using a `HashMap` in one of the methods in my javafx application. This `HashMap` is causing the following `ClassCastException`:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap$Node cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    Map<Integer, ArrayList<WhatsOn>> movieMap = new HashMap<>();

    String whatsOnString = null;
    movieLabels = new Label[]{movie1, movie2, movie3, movie4, movie5, movie6};
    Label[] screenLabels;
    try {
        //get the list of screenings from the database
        whatsOnString = Harness.sendGet("whatson").toString();
        WhatsOn[] whatsOn = JSON.whatsOnFromJson(whatsOnString);

        //set the text of each label to the title of the movie
        for (int i = 0; i < whatsOn.length; i++) {
            if(!movieMap.containsKey(whatsOn[i].getMovie_ID())){
                movieMap.put(whatsOn[i].getMovie_ID(),new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(whatsOn[i])));
            } else {
                ArrayList<WhatsOn> list =  (ArrayList<WhatsOn>)movieMap.get(whatsOn[i].getMovie_ID());
                list.add(whatsOn[i]);
                System.out.println(movieMap.get(whatsOn[i].getMovie_ID()));
            }
        }


        Iterator iterator = movieMap.entrySet().iterator();
        int count = 0;
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            ArrayList<WhatsOn> list = (ArrayList<WhatsOn>) iterator.next();
            setMovieLabel(count, list.get(0));
            for(WhatsOn whatson: list){
            }
            count++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Could not recieve data from database");
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace movieMap.entrySet().iterator(); with movieMap.values().iterator();

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a map's `EntrySet` will produce a series of objects implementing the `Map.Entry` interface. In your case, it seems as though you meant to iterate over the `values()` of the map:

```
Iterator<ArrayList<WhatsOn> iterator = movieMap.values().iterator();
int count = 0;
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    ArrayList<WhatsOn> list = iterator.next();
    setMovieLabel(count, list.get(0));
    for(WhatsOn whatson: list) {
        // Presumably there's some code missing here too
    }
    count++;
}
```